# Google Cloud Spanner Pivot/Coalesce/wide table ability?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Assuming I have the following tables:

**parents**

```
| id    | name    |
-------------------
| 1     | Dave    |
| 2     | Alice   |
```

**children**

```
| id    | parent_id    | child_name  |
---------------------------------------
| 6     | 1            | Clint       |
| 7     | 1            | Oscar       |
| 8     | 2            | Oscar       |
| 9     | 1            | Davey       |
```

Where a parent has many children, is it possible to either pivot the parents table to bring in all the child names like so:

```
| id    | name    | child_name | child_name | child_name |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | Dave    | Clint      | Oscar      | Davey      |
| 2     | Alice   | Oscar      |            |            |
```

and/or query for all Parents who have a Child named "Oscar" or a child named "Davey"?

In Oracle/other SQL engines we could use a `PIVOT` or maybe `COALESCE` function, but in Spanner these are missing and cannot see if this type of query/output is possible?

Answer (score 0):

`PIVOT` looks like a [T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) specific command which isn't in SQL 2011. Cloud Spanner does support the [COALESCE](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators#conditional-expressions) function though.